# How to manually disable/blacklist Maven repository

Tags: maven-2, dependencies, repository

In my base project I use dependency of JasperReports which has non-existent repository declaration in its pom. When I run every Maven commad there is dependency looking for commons-collection in this Jasper repository so I need to wait for timeout.
This is my base project and is used as dependency in my others projects so again I need to wait for timeout.
Is there are a way to move this repository to blacklisted or override this settings?

Notes:
1.Why it search in Jasper repository, maybe bacause of ranges

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>[2.1,)</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

2.My idea to resolve this problem is to change jasper pom and use proxy repository, but I looking to another option.
3.I use jasperreports 1.3.3 version and I'd like don't change it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a way to move this repository to blacklisted or override this settings?

To my knowledge, this is not possible.

> Why does it search in Jasper repository, maybe because of ranges

Yes, I think ranges are "responsible" here of this behavior. Without ranges, Maven wouldn't have to check remote repositories for a newer version than the one available in your local repo.

> My idea to resolve this problem is to change jasper pom and use proxy repository, but I looking to another option.

Fixing jasper pom and using a proxy repository would of course be the ideal solution but this is not always possible. There is maybe a workaround though. Did you try to exclude jasperreports's transitive dependencies that have ranges and to provide them yourself (with fixed version) in your pom instead. Something like this:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
    <!-- Remove Transitive dependencies drawn by Jasper Report that we don't want -->
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      ...
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version><!-- Or whatever version, as long as it's fixed -->
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  ....
<dependencies>
```

This way, Maven shouldn't have to check the non existent repository and this should avoid having to wait for the timeout. I'd give it a try.

> I use jasperreports 1.3.3 version and I'd like don't change it.

No problem.

Comment: @Pascal. Thanks it helps. Ranges in Maven are evil :)

Comment: @cetnar Glad it was useful. And I agree, ranges are not good, they add more problems than solutions.

Comment: Fred's answer below that it can be disabled appears correct, i've just used it. Perhaps a new feature?

Answer (score 24):

Wouldn't the following tell maven to ignore a specific repository:

```
    <repository>
        <id>repo1.maven</id>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

Comment: The above approach is a good way to blacklist a maven repo that's in some transitive dependency's pom.xml, and is causing problems (like the dreaded 301 redirect you get from java.net), where the components already exist in Maven central.

Comment: This very thing happened to me - a dependency had referenced a tech preview repository that had now been replaced by a GA repository.  Used this to block it and all was well in the world, but phew - that's a tough one to track down!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I can still download the jars from this repo.

Comment: The ID must match that used in the declaring POM so here I was to block this lookup `Downloading from mvmsearch: http://www.mvnsearch.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/maven-metadata.xml` the ID of the repository overridden must be `mvmsearch`.

Answer (score 13):

You can override a repo by using a mirrorOf declaration in your settings.xml. Although that not what it's typically intended for, setting for example a mirrorOf on the jasper reports repoid and point it at Central (repo1.maven.org) would effectively make it disappear.

A better option is to use a repository manager like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.com/products/nexus/intro) and then you can control what proxies and artifacts are actually served.

Comment: I disabled java.net by adding to settings.xml (<maven>/conf/settings.xml or ~/.m2/settings.xml) `<settings>...<mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>disabled-jave.net</id>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
            <mirrorOf>http://download.java.net/maven/2</mirrorOf>
        </mirror></mirrors>`